# Is there anyway to make OkHttp request not static?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm planning to make API requests in my application. Though, OkHttp's request body require static parameters, but the params I'm trying to fit in is not static.
Here is the code of the non-static string I want to add as parameter:

```
public String HWID(){
        if (!initial_run()) {
            return const_HWID;
        } else {
            String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
            String unique = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            return manufacturer.charAt(0) + "-" + unique;
        }
    }
```

The initial_run boolean is also non-static as it requires some of the File components:

```
public boolean initial_run(){
        if (file.exists()) return false;
        else{
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos;
                fos = context.openFileOutput("/storage/emulated/0/Download/content.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(HWID().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                fos.close();
                const_HWID = HWID();
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I appreciate any answer that may help me out.

Comment: "OkHttp's request body require static parameters" - why?

Comment: Your [mcve] should show your OkHttp-related code and explain what you mean by static parameters.

Comment: It might seem that the OkHttp module is not the problem, I don't know whether MainActivity class is. However, when I tried to switch the login function to another class, the problem was still there.